# Flutter default profile picture for signup with u8intlist

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

The code below is my signup code, it has everything that I need but I got a problem with the default image. I made the connection with firebase but now I need to **insert a default picture if the person doesn't chose a profile picture**. What is the best way to tackle this?

I use de imagepicker to pick a picture from your own gallery, that is used in a async function called selectimage()

Then the async signup function is the function where the authmethods().signUpUser takes place. In this function it will then say that _image is null and that I can't use the ! operator.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:event_app/pages/Login_Page.dart';
import 'package:event_app/resources/auth_methods.dart';
import 'package:event_app/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import '../utils/colors.dart';
import '../widgets/text_field_input.dart';
import '../widgets/password_field_input.dart';
import 'Verify_Email_Page.dart';

class SignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignupPageState createState() => _SignupPageState();
}

class _SignupPageState extends State<SignupPage> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  Uint8List? _image;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _usernameController.dispose();
  }

  void selectImage() async {
    Uint8List im = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = im;
    });
  }

  void signUpUser() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    String res = await AuthMethods().signUpUser(
        email: _emailController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
        username: _usernameController.text,
        file: _image!);

    if (res == "Success") {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const VerifyEmailPage()));
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });

      showSnackBar(res, context);
    }
  }

  void navigateToLogin() {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginPage()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Container(),
              flex: 2,
            ),
            SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/ic_instagram.svg',
              color: textColor,
              height: 64,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 64,
            ),
            Stack(
              children: [
                _image != null
                    ? CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 64,
                        backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image!),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      )
                    : const CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 64,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                            'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png'),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                Positioned(
                    bottom: -10,
                    left: 80,
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: selectImage,
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo)))
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24,
            ),
            TextFieldInput(
              hintText: 'Enter your username',
              textInputType: TextInputType.text,
              textEditingController: _usernameController,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24,
            ),
            TextFieldInput(
              hintText: 'Enter your email',
              textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              textEditingController: _emailController,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24,
            ),
            PasswordFieldInput(
              hintText: 'Enter your password',
              textInputType: TextInputType.text,
              textEditingController: _passwordController,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24,
            ),
            InkWell(
              child: Container(
                child: !_isLoading
                    ? const Text('Sign up')
                    : const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: textColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                width: double.infinity,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                  ),
                  color: accentColor,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: signUpUser,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(),
              flex: 2,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: const Text("Already have an account?"),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: navigateToLogin,
                  child: Container(
                    child: const Text(
                      "Login.",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the `selectImage` function from async to sync function to prevent api call before `_image` is set.

```
void selectImage(){
    pickImage(ImageSource.gallery).then(
    (im){
     setState(() {
      _image = im;
    });
    });
    
  }
```